# Does SpreadsheetGear have intellisense support for in-built or custom functions?

Tags: spreadsheetgear

I am using SpreadsheetGear to integrate with my WPF project, and I have developed a few custom functions. Is there a way to display the function names and parameters as intellisense when the user starts typing the formula in the cell?

Answer (score 1):

SpreadsheetGear does not yet support something like Excel's "formula builder" / IntelliSense-like feature, unfortunately.